# Multi-targeting `net461` and `netcoreapp2.0`

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have a command line .NET application that should compile against only ported .NET Core components when built as a .NET core app, but can additionally reference legacy .NET framework modules when built that way.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ProjectGuid>{48B4C337-CD13-4826-B6A1-DA97CE71511B}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Microsoft.Pc</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Pc</AssemblyName>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <OutputPath>$(PSdkFolder)\Binaries</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompilerCore\CompilerCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompilerCore\CompilerCore.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LegacyCompiler\LegacyCompiler.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompilerService\CompilerService.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Despite this, I get these errors

```
"D:\Source\Repos\P\P.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CommandLine\CommandLine.csproj.metaproj" (default target) (20) ->
"D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CommandLine\CommandLine.csproj" (default target) (21) ->
"D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CommandLine\CommandLine.csproj" (Build target) (21:3) ->
(_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1601,5): error : Project 'D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\LegacyCompiler\LegacyCompiler.csproj' targets 'net461'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. [D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CommandLine\CommandLine.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1601,5): error : Project 'D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CompilerService\CompilerService.csproj' targets 'net461'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. [D:\Source\Repos\P\Src\Pc\CommandLine\CommandLine.csproj]
```

Why is it complaining that LegacyCompiler.csproj targets 'net461' while CommandLine targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0' when that dependency should be excluded in this case?

**Update:** these are the `.csproj` files for the other projects. As this project is open-source, I'm posting links to the files:

[CompilerCore.csproj](https://github.com/p-org/P/blob/ssa/Src/Pc/CompilerCore/CompilerCore.csproj)

[CommandLine.csproj](https://github.com/p-org/P/blob/ssa/Src/Pc/CommandLine/CommandLine.csproj)

[LegacyCompiler.csproj](https://github.com/p-org/P/blob/ssa/Src/Pc/LegacyCompiler/LegacyCompiler.csproj)

Comment: All I can say is that it's correct way to do that, and it was (and is) always working for me.

Comment: @Evk -- that's what all the documentation I've been able to find has suggested, too. I'm gonna add the .csproj's for the other two projects...

Comment: If you won't be able to resolve this - you can post minimal reproducable example (VS solution with empty projects) somewhere, so people can look at it.

Comment: This project is open-source. You can clone from the `ssa` branch here https://github.com/p-org/P/tree/ssa

Comment: I should mention that I'm compiling with `msbuild`. Maybe there's a flag I'm missing? Can I use the `dotnet build` command to build the .NET 4.6.1 target?

Comment: @downvoter -- care to leave a comment?

Comment: I just tried and `dotnet build` builds multitarget csproj for me, at least on windows. So you can try with that, and also try with regular VS build to see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165451/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-evk).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.Net Standard` class library with the version that is supported by both `.Net Core` and `.Net 4.6.1` (as I may guess from your `.csproj` file).